# Use a template base on class instance type

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to display a template based on an array of classes. I am not sure how I would do something like this.

I have created two templates that would be referenced by a for loop. The template looks something like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">
    <!-- Show one of the templates here -->
  </li>
</ul>

<ng-template #buttonTemplate>
  <button>Some Text</button>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #linkTemplate>
  <a href="">Some Text</a>
</ng-template>
```

Next I created a javascript component that looks something like this:

```js
@Component({ /* Options */ })
export class MyComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.items = [
      new ButtonClass(),
      new LinkClass(),
      new ButtonClass()
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, how would I use `#buttonTemplate` when the item is `instanceof ButtonClass` and use `#linkTemplate` when the item is `instanceof LinkClass`?

Comment: can't you use a `*ngIf` to check that ? `*ngIf="item instanceOf LinkClass"`

Comment: You could create components. And then use `ngFor` with `ngComponentOutlet` to render any components in a loop you need

Comment: you could create a function and pass the value to it `*ngIf="isInstanceOf(value, 'ButtonClass')"

Comment: @Nicolas IDK I am new to Angular, what if there are more than 2 types, is there an `else if`?

Comment: No, there isn't. You will  need multiple ngIfs

Comment: You could also use a ngSwitch. `[ngSwitch]="true"` with `*ngSwitchCase="item instanceOf LinkClass"`. we are using `[ngSwitch]="true"` because we want to check which expression evaluate to true.

Comment: What about using dynamic components with `ViewChild`?

Comment: @J.Pichardo do you have an example of how that can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is using `@ViewChild`, this allowed me to return a template to `ngTemplateOutlet`.

So my html didn't change much except for the new `ng-template` in the `for` loop.

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="item | getTemplate : buttonTemplate : linkTemplate; context: {$implicit: {model: item, /* other properties */}}">
  </li>
</ul>

<ng-template #buttonTemplate let-item>
  <button>{{item.model.text}}</button>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #linkTemplate let-item>
  <a href="{{item.model.endpoint}}">{{item.model.text}}</a>
</ng-template>
```

In my JavaScript/TypeScript I added a `@ViewChild`, and a function that takes an item and tests the reference and returns the proper `TemplateRef`.

```js
@Component({ /* Options */ })
export class MyComponent {

  @ViewChild('buttonTemplate', { static: true })
  public buttonTemplate

  @ViewChild('linkTemplate', { static: true })
  public linkTemplate

  public items = [
    new ButtonClass(),
    new LinkClass(),
    new ButtonClass()
  ]

  getTemplate(item) {
    if(item instanceof ButtonClass) return this.buttonTemplate
    if(item instanceof LinkClass) return this.linkTemplate
  }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that having directly methods in the `HTML isn't a good practice with the angular lifecycle (chekc [this article](https://blog.appverse.io/why-it-is-a-bad-idea-to-use-methods-in-the-html-templates-with-angular-2-30d49f0d3b16) for more details)

Comment: Okay thanks! Here is another [article](https://dzone.com/articles/why-we-shound-not-use-function-inside-angular-temp)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `*ngIf then else`

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">
     <ng-container *ngIf="item instanceOf LinkClass; then buttonTemplate else linkTemplate"></ng-container>
  </li>
</ul>

<ng-template #buttonTemplate>
  <button>Some Text</button>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #linkTemplate>
  <a href="">Some Text</a>
</ng-template>
```

With more than 2 template:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">
     <ng-container *ngIf="item instanceOf XXX; then template1"></ng-container>
     <ng-container *ngIf="item instanceOf XXX; then template2"></ng-container>
     <ng-container *ngIf="item instanceOf XXX; then template3"></ng-container>
     <ng-container *ngIf="item instanceOf XXX; then template4"></ng-container>
  </li>
</ul>
```

To passe data to your template, you need to do so:

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{myData:item}"
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="item instanceOf XXX ? template_A: null"></ng-container>
```

and

```
<ng-template #template_A let-myData='myData'>
  {{ myData.name }}
</ng-template>
```

**EDIT** : You can't use `instance of` in the HTML. So you have two alternatives at least:

- use function to assert the class equality:

```
*ngIf="isInstanceOfXXX(item); then X else X"
```

with

```
isInstanceOfXXX(item:any): item is ClassX{
   return item instance of ClassX;
}
```

- Map your items to add a new field with the class name inside for example:

```
items = items.map(item => ({...item,type: item.constructor.name}))
```

and in your html:

```
*ngIf="item.type === 'ClassX'; then X else X"
```

But be carefull with the last method, ClassX.name is an ES6 feature hence it does not work in IE11

Comment: How would you handle more than 2 templates?

Comment: probably would use `ngSwitchCase` syntax in this instance

Comment: @c_ogoo you are totally right!! But I don't see how to use `instance of` with it.

Comment: This won't let me use both `*ngTemplateOutlet` and `*ngIf` on the same element how would I pass additional data to the template?

Comment: Looking better! However I get `Error: Unexpected token 'instanceOf'`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pipe to perform the instanceof operation.

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import type { PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'instanceof',
  pure: true,
})
export class InstanceofPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform<V, R>(value: V, Type: abstract new (...args: any) => R): R | undefined {
    return value instanceof Type ? value : undefined;
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as shows the example below.

In the component TS file:

```
  public readonly B = B;
  public readonly C = C;
```

In the component template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of list">
  <p *ngIf="item | instanceof: B as b" class="b">{{ b.valueA }} {{ b.valueB }}</p>
  <p *ngIf="item | instanceof: C as c" class="c">{{ c.valueA }} {{ c.valueC }}</p>
</ng-container>
```

[Full example at Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-az5nlu?file=src/app/app.component.html)